# split paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am new to GUI and I am writing a program to display several entries of NameRecord on a graph. I started the whole frame in paintComponent when I only needed to put in one entry.

However, now I need to modify it so that there is storage for multiple entries of NameRecords, which I decided to use ArrayList to store. Then I want to be able to search, clear these entries. But what I have in paintComponent is just too messy.

How can I modify this method so that I have separate classes to store entries and perform other methods? Since I cannot refer to g outside of this class.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    w = getWidth();
    h = getHeight();

    //draw horizontal lines
    g.drawLine(0, 20, w, 20);
    g.drawLine(0, h - 20, w, h - 20);

    //draw vertical lines
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        g.drawLine((w / 12) * i, 0, (w / 12) * i, h);
    }
    //draw lable of years
    g.drawString("   1900", 0, 13);
    g.drawString("   1900", 0, h - 7);

    int year = 1900;
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
        g.drawString("   " + Integer.toString(year + (i * 10)), (w / 12 * i), 13);
        g.drawString("   " + Integer.toString(year + (i * 10)), (w / 12 * i), h - 7);
    }

    // draw line of rank
    if (nameData != null) {
        nameList.add(nameData);
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            g.drawLine((w / 12 * i), convertValue(nameData.getRank(i)),
                    (w / 12) * (i + 1), convertValue(nameData.getRank(i + 1)));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            String label = " ";
            label = (nameData.getName() + " " + nameData.getRank(i));
            g.drawString(label, (w / 12 * i), convertValue(nameData.getRank(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Also I used another class to do all GUI displays(I am not sure if that is the way to say it, but it calls actionPerformed method). Their connections are kind of confusing to me. I will just put it here as a reference.

```
 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String s = e.getActionCommand();

    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("graph")) {
        doGraph();
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("search")) {
        findName(inputField.getText());
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("clear all")) {
        clear();
        //– remove all names from the NameGraph

    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("clear one")) {

        //remove the name that was added to the NameGraph earliest.
    } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        // This is the response to the Enter Key pressed in inputField.
        doGraph();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Since I cannot refer to g outside of this class.* **why?**

Comment: Sry I mean the paintComponent  method

Comment: Create methods which take a reference to `Graphics`, from your `paintComponent` method, pass it's `Graphics` reference to them...

Comment: Why can you refer to `g` outside of the paintComponent method?

Comment: I actually don't know the answer. I just feel like what I have for now is too long for the paintComponent method, and the point is I don't know how to separate all these parts from it. I guess I still need to call stuff like g.drawLine if I separate them out?

Comment: @YuheZhu If the codes is for drawing, it will be in your paintComponent or be called by paintComponent. You can't really remove them and sever their link to the panel responsible for drawing them. As for how to split the drawing task out to individual objects, you can take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I modify this method so that I have separate classes to store entries and perform other methods? Since I cannot refer to g outside of this class.

You will able to access the `Graphics object g` by ***passing it to a method*** or a method of another class:

```
//for example
class MyGraph{
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        //implements how the graph is drawn, for e.g:
        //g.drawLine(x, y);
    }
}
```

In the panel class which is displaying the drawings:

```
class DisplayPanel extends JPanel{

    private MyGraph;

    public DisplayPanel(){
        MyGraph graph = new MyGraph();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        graph.draw(g);            //let the objects draw themselves
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! My class actually extends JComponent because that is what I get from my professor's given code, and then I have another class extends JFrame. Is that gonna affect anything?